# Why this solution to codewars challenge is taking so much time that it gets 'Execution Timed Out'?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming in python so I don't know why this solution is not effective
Code:

```
def check(seq, elem):
    i=0
    b=0
    while i<len(seq):
        while (b==0):
            if (seq[i]==elem):
                b=1
                i+=1
                return(True)
        else:
            return(False)
```

Problem: [link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57cc975ed542d3148f00015b/train/python)

EDIT:
Thanks to one comment I spotted infinite loop but still it is not effective and I don't know why
EDITED CODE:

```
def check(seq, elem):
    i=0
    b=0
    while (b==0) and (i<len(seq)):
        if (seq[i]==elem):
            b=1
            i+=1
            return(True)
    else:
        return(False)
```

Comment: it is going into infinite loop take an example where element is not present in the list..!

Comment: Try `return elem in seq` as the whole of the function code: it returns True if it is in. As code gets more complex you need to use the efficient approaches which Python provides. You could also try out [link](https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit) to step through your code, watch what is happening, and find bugs.

Comment: your `i` will only increment when if condition satisfy. you need to shift `i+=1` outside the `if` see my code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Testcases:**  like `check([1,2,3],4)` your code will go into infinite loop. {when `ele` **not present in list** it will tends to infinite}

Optimization. you can do by single `for/while` loop only.

**Code:**

```
def check(seq, elem):
    for num in seq:
        if num == elem:
            return True
    return False
            
print(check([1,2,3],4)) #False
```

**Code:**

```
def check(seq, elem):
    i=0
    while i < len(seq):
        if seq[i] == elem:
            return True
        i += 1
    return False
print(check([1,2,3],4)) #False
```

Comment: worst case scenario is `O(n)` reason to check every element till last. which i think is better time complexity. although if your `list` is in `sorted` manner you can apply binary search. time complexity will be `O(log(n))` @Verpanther